# Jinja2 template does value exist in array?

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

Is there a way while using templating in ansible to see if a value exists in an array without using a loop to go through the array?

eg.

vars file:

```
my_data_array: [ "valueA", "valueB", "valueC" ]
```

template section example:

```
{% if ("valueA" in my_data_array) %}
<templateinformation>
{% endif %}
```

I've also tried (both with and without brackets):

```
{% if ("valueA" in my_data_array) %}
```

and:

```
{% if {{ "valueA" in my_data_array }} %}
```

*(**update**) and:

```
{% "valueA" in my_data_array %}
```

and a couple of others now as well. Most come back with syntax errors.  What I am looking for is something similar to PHP's **in_array()** function, or Python's **in** command where it returns a boolean if the value is in the array.  The ansible jinja2 support seems to include it only if it is a string within a string.

Am I doing something wrong or is this unsupported and I'll have to setup a loop?

Comment: If you are going to mark this as duplicate I'd like some clarification on how asking about how asking how to use **in** in jinja2 is a duplicate of using the jinja2 template commands to include other files.

Comment: I am going to close questions as duplicate according to how it is done on SO. If a question has an answer under another question, it is considered duplicate. And this question is a clear-cut duplicate.　That you forgot `if` when writing your "updated" statement does not qualify this question for reopening as it is of no value to other users.

Comment: @techraf guys the linked answer marked as duplicated has nothing to do with this question; wrong link?

Comment: i think techraf may have been trying to correct my syntax at the time rather than pointing at an actual duplicate question. That was essentially the main issue with what I was trying above.

Comment: Really need it this question answered...

Comment: I concur that this has been marked as a duplicate in error. The linked question does not contain an answer related to checking for the existence of a value in a Jinja array.

Comment: The duplicate is correct `{% if "valueA" in my_data_array %}` is what should be used in this particular case.